# useing verbs with "ing"

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "the sun is shining" I wonder if I want to refer to right now, I can use 'ing' or not in this case.

I am also sure how to say "a bag is in my hand now". I s it correct to say "I am holding a bag?"

How can I understand if I can use a verb in a sentences with "ing" or not? Is there any rule?

forexample is it correct to ask "is he smiling?"

Answer (score -2):

All sentences are correct, except for *"I am holding a bag?"*. Remember that interrogative questions must include the auxiliary verb (to be) before the subject, in this case, *I*, so the sentence should be *Am I holding a bag?*.

The present continuous tense (e.g. *The sun is shining*) is used for actions that are happening right now, as we're speaking, which means that they're usually actions that require some time to be completed.

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical to [not use inversion in a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/112766/191178) and rely on intonation or a question mark to make it clear it's a question. There's nothing grammatically wrong with "I am holding a bag?" (although I'd prefer "I'm" instead of "I am").

Comment: It’s definitely correct to not use inversion in a question, but I suggested it wouldn’t be correct because of the lack of coherence. Let me explain: It can be used in questions that, for example, ask for a confirmation rather than a developed answer, e.g. *You’re going to buy the car?*, and even then, these questions have a “So” or “...right?” within. In my opinion, not using inversion has the same effect here, the person is asking for confirmation rather than asking if they’re actually holding a bag, which doesn’t make a lot of sense, and I repeat, it’s my opinion, not an absulute truth.

Comment: Your further explanation makes no sense. It's the equivalent of saying that "That hurts!" is ungrammatical because we don't know what the pronoun refers to. You're confusing semantics with grammar.